# How to call a Subclass as a Superclass Type

Tags: java, superclass

i'm currently learning inheritance and I'm having some trouble understanding the concept.
For the following code could someone tell me why I can't declare a subclass of type Superclass?

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Superclass myA = new Superclass();
    Superclass myB = new Subclass();
    }
public class Superclass{
    private string a;

    public Superclass()
    {
        a="";
    }
    public void setA(String userA)
    {
        a = userA;     
    }
}
public class Subclass extends Superclass{
    private String b;

    public Subclass()
    {
        b = "";
    }
    public void setB(String userB)
    {
        b = userB;
    }
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.print(b)
    }
}
```

myA doesnt give me any problems, but myB does. I want to be make an array of lets say Superclass,
but I want to be able to use the Subclass.Something like this

```
Superclass[] X = new Superclass[2];
x[0] = new Subclass();
X[0].setB("hello");
X[0].display();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning subclass object to a superclass type variable(i.e,upcasting is done), its fine.
But when u do that, only superclass methods can be accessed. So in order to access the subclass methods please do downcast to its subclass type.
eg.

```
    Superclass[] X = new Superclass[2];
    X[0] = new Subclass();
    ((Subclass) X[0]).setB("hello");
    ((Subclass) X[0]).display();
```

Answer (score 0):

The main fun here is whenever you call any method on a reference that method should be present in its class declaration.

The method can be called or not is decided on reference type but which instance of implementation is to be called is decided on its object type.

since you do not have a `setB()` method in `SuperClass` compiler doesnt know where this method came from and so it gives compile time error.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Rename `setB()` in your subclass as `setA()`, add the function `display()` to your SuperClass and call `setA()` on your Subclass as `X[0].setA("hello");` and you will see how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this - change setA() and setB() to set() - and your code will work. The behavior is called *polymorphism* and is one of the main concepts of OO programming.

```
public class Superclass{
    private string a;

    public Superclass()
    {
        a="";
    }
    public void set(String userA)
    {
        a = userA;     
    }
}
public class Subclass extends Superclass{
    private String b;

    public Subclass()
    {
        b = "";
    }
    @override
    public void set(String userB)
    {
        b = userB;
    }
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.print(b)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to assign a **subclass type object** to it's **super class type object X[0].**

So it does not showing any error while assigning it. But you are allowed to call those method in subclass which has the same name as in superclass.

For example

If you **rename** **setB()** to **setA()**, you can find your expected result but you can't call setB()

Now try to assign **myB=X[0];** and run

You will get this error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Now if you create a new object of Subclass i.e Subclass **subc=new Subclass();**

and try to **assign X[0] to subc, subc=X[0];**
you'll get this error , incompatible type (required subclass , found superclass)

Answer (score 0):

your X variable is of type Superclass, so you can only access visible methods and attributes in this class or in its super classes (super classes of Superclass but not it's sub classes).
The problem why you think you can call `setB()` method is that you are seeing the object type you are assigning to `Superclass[] X` which is new `Superclass[2]`, so what happens when you get a reference to such an object as an attribute in a method? you don't even know it's callers, what methods of it's sub classes you can guess and call if it even have sub classes? **you can't**